# Java Fibonacci series

Tags: java, arrays, fibonacci

What would be the next step in order to ask the user which of the numbers in this series of 30 he wants to see and prompts for an integer input - a number between 1 and 30 (inclusive)?

So if the user wants to see the fifth (5th) number of the Fibonacci series the user would input the integer 5 in response to the prompt.

```
public class MyFibonacci {
    public static void main(String a[]) {
         int febCount = 30;
         int[] feb = new int[febCount];
         feb[0] = 0;
         feb[1] = 1;
         for(int i=2; i < febCount; i++) {
             feb[i] = feb[i-1] + feb[i-2];
         }

         for(int i=0; i< febCount; i++) {
                 System.out.print(feb[i] + " ");
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Scanner`, or some `InputStreamReader` to read the input from the console. `Scanner` would be used in this way:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
if(scanner.hasNextInt())
    int someInt = scanner.nextInt();
```

Another option would be to use some reader like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

and parse the required data from the output of the reader. Using `Scanner` will be simpler in most cases though.

Answer (score 0):

**Here you go :**

```
 public class TestProgram {

    public static void main(String a[]) {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        printFibonacciSeries();
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Fibonacci Series, Enter the number in the series of 30 you want to see");
        int num = reader.nextInt();
        int febCount = 30;
        int[] feb = new int[febCount];
        feb[0] = 0;
        feb[1] = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i < febCount; i++) {
            feb[i] = feb[i - 1] + feb[i - 2];

            if (i == num) {
                System.out.print(feb[i] + " ");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printFibonacciSeries() {

        int febCount = 31;
        int[] feb = new int[febCount];
        feb[0] = 0;
        feb[1] = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i < febCount; i++) {
            feb[i] = feb[i - 1] + feb[i - 2];
            System.out.print(feb[i] + " ");

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: this is perfect the only issue I'm having is getting the program to print the numbers (up to 30 in the series) before asking the user to select the numbers

Comment: Your second for-loop in the `main` method is weird. Why don't you just remove the for-loop and replace what's inside of it (`if (i == num) { System.out.print(feb[i] + " "); }`) with `System.out.print(feb[num] + " ");` ?

Comment: @Ritesh Karwa  Are you able to get 30th element from the series?

Comment: @VNT did not actually get your question? if you want the 30th element just 
make int febCount = 31;

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Fibonacci_series  // upto less than a given number
{
    public static void main(long n)
    {
        long a=0, b=1, c=0;
        while (c<n)
        {
            a=b;
            b=c;
            System.out.print(c+", ");
            c=a+b;
        }
        System.out.print("....");
    }
}
```

Comment: `public static void main(long n)` will not be an executable entry point

Answer (score 0):

You could use a command line argument and read it from the main method args:

```
public class MyFibonacci {
    public static void main(String a[]) throws NumberFormatException {
         int febCount = Integer.parseInt(a[0]);
```

then call it with

```
java MyFibonacci 30
```

Or pass it in the 'VM options' input in an IntelliJ run configuration